# How can I make one key do these 2 things?

Tags: automation, counter

Thanks in advance for the help. I have a job that requires repetitive keystrokes. To make my job easier, I need to do the following 2 things:

```
LButton::Send {LButton}{Tab}{Enter}
```

2nd: Count every time LButton is pressed.

Right now, I'm using 2 separate keystrokes:
1 above
and
2 - Spacebar to count, like this:

```
Counter=0
Space::Counter++
F12::MsgBox, %Counter%
```

So right now, I need to hit the LButton to perform my job task (left mouse, tab, enter) AND the Spacebar to count each time I do this.

I'd like to press the Left mouse, and make it do the left mouse, tab, enter sequence PLUS count the click. That way, I wouldn't have to press the spacebar each time I needed to count the action (for accuracy and ease of use).

Any idea how I could set up autohotkey to do this in a single click?

Thanks again. I've learned a ton from combing through the suggestions, and I'm enjoying how much easier my work has become with AHK.

Best,
Jesse

Comment: I actually figured this out!